# Oracle Database 12 c , SQL Server Translator Is not Translating query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jdbc

I have installed SQLServer Translators as oracle document require to use 12 c jdbc jar so i replace this jar with jdbc jar.
I have created transport and created profile using sqldeveloper. I have followed steps given in oracle documentation 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/sql_transl_install.htm#DRDAA29457

Now after completing installation my sqlserver profile has following parameters

```
 Profile_name SQLSERVER_PROFILE
 Translator "MON422_QA"."SQLSERVER_TSQL_TRANSLATOR"
 Foreign_SQL_syntax True
 Translate_new_sql True
 Raise_translation_error false
 Log_translationerro flase
 Trace_translation false
```

I have installed for migration user and now when I am trying to use for different user I have given execute grant to target user.

But I am unable to translate sql query

```
Select top 1 * from dual;
```

Translator is not working as expected. If any additional information is required please let me know I will add the information.

**EDIT** 
Query I am trying to run

```
 Select cast ( 5 to NVARCHAR2(50)) from dual;
```

Should be translated to

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(5) FROM DUAL:
```

But it says query terminated undesired parenthesis after `NVARCHAR2`;

We can see translated queries using sqldeveloper for translator profile being used. But my queries are not being translated at all.

Reference For Translator FrameWork

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/sql_transl_install.htm#DRDAA29148

Comment: `Translator is not working as expected` - what is wrong ? Do you get any error ? If yes, then please show the error message.Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. `

Comment: SQLServer does not have a table called `dual` -- that's an Oracle specific special table.

Comment: @krokodilko select cast (5 as NVARCHAR2(50)) from dual  doesnot get translated and gives error saying query terminated '(' saying undesired paranthesis after NVARCHAR2 and there is no translated query for query to be translated it should have translated query which we can see at sqldeveloper.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I am using oracle my queries are sqlserver query but has to be translated as it is being used for oracle database.

Comment: Okay then, `TOP 1` is not valid Oracle syntax. It's enough to do `Select 1 from dual`; the table has only one row.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thanks for suggestion, but please follow the the reference https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/sql_transl_install.htm#DRDAA29148, I know  <code> TOP 1 </code> is not valid Oracle syntax. Thats why I am using translator which will translate from sqlserver queries to oracle query. It should translate to SELECT * From Dual where rownum <=1;

Comment: It should translate from 'select top 1 * from dual ' to 'SELECT * FROM dual WHERE ROWNUM <=1;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server translator assumes it is receiving T-SQL or a SQL Server SQL statement in order to translate it.

If you want to use the translation framework to translate an oracle statement to another version of an oracle statement - you can totally do that. But you do not involve the SQL Server translator.

You simply add an entry in your translation profile, a 'template' of the SQL you want translated, and you also provide what you want to come out the other end.

[Kerry wrote a very nice blog post demonstrating that here.](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2013/07/sql-translation-framework/)